# ImageMagick's convert outputs garbled image

Tags: python, flask, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I have the code below. For some reason it outputs this garbled image:

[image]

**original:**

[image]

(I'm not allowed to use any ready-made Python libraries in this exercise)

```
@app.route("/flip", methods=["POST"])
def flip():

    # retrieve parameters from html form
    if 'horizontal' in request.form['mode']:
        direction = 90
    elif 'vertical' in request.form['mode']:
        direction = -90

    filename = request.form['image']

    # open and process image
    target = os.path.join(APP_ROOT, 'static/images')
    destination = "/".join([target, filename])

    img = Image.open(destination)
    subprocess.call(['C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.0.10-Q16-HDRI\magick.exe', 'convert',  f'{destination}', '-rotate', f'{direction}', f'{destination}'], shell=True)
    # save and return image
    destination = "/".join([target, 'flipped.jpg'])
    if os.path.isfile(destination):
        os.remove(destination)
    img.save(destination)
    return send_image('flipped.jpg')
```

EDIT: when I set the destination image in `subprocess.call` to `flipped.jpg` - the output is the original image. Why?

Comment: You almost certainly don't want `magick.exe convert INPUT OUTPUT` because that causes specific, rarely needed behaviour. You more likely want `magick.exe INPUT OUTPUT` so omit `'convert'`. Though I doubt that will fix it. Try the command stand-alone in a Command Prompt and see if it behaves the same, if so, we can exclude Python as the cause.

Comment: Please share the **exact** input image file too - is it JPEG or PNG?

Comment: Why have you got `img = Image.open()` and `img.save()` in there? You are not supposed to be using PIL.

Comment: @MarkSetchell jpg. Correct, I forgot to remove the PIL stuff.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Still - how can I convert the source image to the rotated image, so that the input to every call to ```flip``` would rotate the latest (rotated) image? Meaning, how can I re-write the PIL code without using PIL?

Comment: You didn't answer my question. Can you achieve the desired effect in your Command Prompt using `magick INPUT -flip OUTPUT`? Or by replacing `-flip` with `-flop` or `-rotate 90` or similar?

Comment: The first option works in Python.

Comment: Excellent, so is that the solution you wanted?

Comment: Partially. How can I save the result image without using PIL?

Comment: What do you mean? You aren't using **PIL** - you used **ImageMagick**.

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

```
    if 'horizontal' in request.form['mode']:
        direction = 'flip'
    elif 'vertical' in request.form['mode']:
        direction = 'flop'
        filename = request.form['image']

    # open and process image
    target = os.path.join(APP_ROOT, 'static/images')
    destination = "/".join([target, filename])
    subprocess.call(['C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.0.10-Q16-HDRI\magick.exe', 
                     'convert',  f'{destination}', '-'f'{direction}', f'{destination}'], 
                     shell=True)
    return send_image(filename)
```

Comment: Why do you persist with `magick convert INPUT OPERATIONS OUTPUT`? You should use `magick INPUT OPERATIONS OUTPUT` **without** `convert` like I suggested in the comments.